# Using image blob files from a web application as input to a python program

Tags: python, blob

I have created a react web application, where canvas images are stored as file blobs in jpeg format. How do I use these blobs as input to a python program that classifies images?

The blob generating function is as follows:

```
clearCanvas({nativeEvent}) {

  this.canvas.toBlob(
   function(canvasDataBlob) { // anonymous callback with a handle to Blob
    var url=window.URL.createObjectURL(canvasDataBlob, {autoRevoke: true});
    var image=new Image();
    image.src=url;
    image.download="my-image.jpeg";
    document.body.appendChild(image);
   },
   "image/jpeg", 1.0 // optional arguments: MIME type and quality level
  );
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to [create a download link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server) from that blob and manually run a Python script on the downloaded image.

I assume that instead you want to display the classification result in the same web page. For this you have to make an XMLHttpRequest to a Python web server, which will then process the image and send the the classification back to the browser. See [Sending and Receiving Binary Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Sending_binary_data) (MDN) for how to create such a request.

If you don't already have a web server I suggest you look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/). But this is not the place to explain this all, and good tutorials do exist.

If this answer doesn't help I suggest to make a more specific question. Tell us what problem you are trying to solve (instead of just the solution you think you need), and tell us where you think this Python program should be running, or if you already have it running and know how it can receive/decode the image, what you have already tried or read.